# Clear the storage persistent flag for a website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, storage

I'm using the `navigator.storage.persist()` API on Chrome, and have managed to get it set to `true`. But I would like to (at least for testing) be able to clear the setting putting back to `false`.

The API definition does not include a method or flag to clear as far as I can tell. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager  and the living standard: https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/#storagemanager

However, for my purposes it would also be acceptable if there was a way from 'Site settings', the clear cache options, or even a custom page like the chrome://appcache-internals/ page for appcache.

If not, where does the flag get stored? i.e. what would I need to delete in the file system to reset things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I has not been able to find a way to clear the flag for a *specific* website.

But for testing purposes (as you requested), the flag returned by the `StorageManager.persisted()` can be cleared by:

1. navigate to `chrome://settings/?search=cooki`
2. click on `Clear browsing data`
3. select `Cookies and other site data` in the popup and click `Clear
   data` button

After performing the above steps, `StorageManager.persisted()` starts to return `false`.