# List all `navigator.storage` files / Clear storage cache

Tags: javascript, navigator, web-storage

I store multiple large assets in `navigator.storage`, to avoid large downloads.

With it, I would like to do the following as well:

1. "List" - to show all the saved files
2. "Clear cache" - to delete all files saved to `navigator.storage`

I could not find a method to perform either.

##### Alternatives attempted

I have attempted to store the files directory in `localStorage`, however, this information can be cleared without the files being removed, and the user ends up with inflated storage use for unknown documents.

Comment: Will this answer your question regarding clear cache : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52390843/4116300

Comment: @RohìtJíndal no, as i would like to do this programatically

Answer (score 0):

With localStorage you can easily add and remove datas:

```
function addToStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', 'red');
  localStorage.setItem('font', 'Helvetica');
  localStorage.setItem('image', 'mydog.png');
}

function clearStorage() {
  localStorage.clear();
}

function removeStorageItem(item) {
  localStorage.removeItem(item);

}

addToStorage();
removeStorageItem('image');
clearStorage();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not address `navigator.storage`, and `localStorage` is not a good method for file storage

Comment: Did you mean saving data to browser cache and then delete saved files?
Not shure you can for security reasons.

Comment: Can you tell me the context of your need? Because, when writing a service worker for PWA, you can put file and remove files from cache.

Answer (score -1):

`navigator.storage` is not a storage location, which your question seems to imply. Rather, it is a **storage manager** that you can use to request that data be persisted, using `navigator.storage.persist()`. That method will persist data in the following stores:

- Cache API
- Cookies
- DOM Storage (Local Storage)
- File System API (browser-provided and sandboxed file system)
- IndexedDB
- Service workers

See the ["Persistent Storage" article on web.dev](https://web.dev/persistent-storage/#what-storage-is-protected-by-persistent-storage) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. As I now understand it, when I do `navigator.storage.getDirectory`, it is using the `File System API`, which is what I want to forcibly clear and can't find a way to do so